# How to create and and edit nested objects in rails 3.2?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

So I have two models, Reports and Receipts. Each report has many receipts. I used scaffolding to generate all my views and stuff but Im changing things around so that when a user creates a new report or edits one, they can create and edit receipts in the form.

My models are set up:

```
class Report < ActiveRecord::Base

    has_many :receipts, :dependent => :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :receipts, :allow_destroy => true

    attr_protected :id

end
class Receipt < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :report

    attr_protected :id

    validates_presence_of :vendor, :date, :description, :amount, :acctCode
end
```

I have the form set up to create a new receipt:

```
    <%= form_for @report do |f| %>
     ....
       <%= f.fields_for :receipts, Receipt.new do |receipt| %>
       ...
       <% end %>
    <% end %>
```

But every time I go to save a report, I get a routing error:

```
No route matches {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"receipts", :report_id=>#<Receipt id: nil, date: nil, vendor: "", description: "", amount: nil, companyCard: false, lobbyingExpense: false, acctCode: "", created_at: nil, updated_at: nil, report_id: 2>}
```

and my routes are set up as:

```
resources :reports do
    resources :receipts
end
```

and my controller for receipts has

```
  # GET /receipts/new
  def new
    @receipt = Receipt.new

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # new.html.erb
    end
  end

  # GET /receipts/1/edit
  def edit
    @receipt = Receipt.find(params[:id])
  end

  # POST /receipts
  def create
    @receipt = Receipt.new(params[:receipt])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @receipt.save
        format.html { redirect_to @receipt.Report, notice: 'Receipt was successfully created.' }
      else
        format.html { render action: "new" }
      end
    end
  end
```

I havent touched rails in a while so Im not sure what Im doing wrong. But in my older apps (3.1) when I added images to say, blog posts, I didnt even have a controller for images other than to delete them via ajax. The only reason I have a controller here for receipts is because I used scaffolds to generate the views and such.

edit - I should also point out, that if I go to the new receipt view, I get an error on the form tag:

```
<%= form_for(@receipt) do |receipt| %>

undefined method `receipts_path'
```

Comment: provide code of create/update action. It seems to me problem is not in the form. However your f.fields_for is strange.

Comment: I would use `@report.receipts.build` instead of `Receipt.new`. Don't think that will fix your problem though.

Comment: Added my controller for receipts. also - @report.receipts.build actually gives me the same routing error...

Comment: For your last problem (on `form_for(@receipt)`), you need to pass also the `Report` : `form_for [@report, @receipt] ...` because it's a nested resources (ie the path contains both the id of the report and the id of the receipt)

Comment: maybe the shallow option may help you : 2.7.2 in http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#nested-resources

Answer (score 1):

If you are using `accepts_nested_attributes_for` you don't need an extra controller to manage the records. Of course if you need specific pages like a "show view" for a receipt you need that controller.

To get `accepts_nested_attributes_for` you need:

1. A form for your report
2. use `fields_for :receipts` in that form

This way you can edit all created receipts for a given report. If you also want to create new receipts you can add a blank receipt with: `@report.receipts.build`. You can add this call to your `new` and `edit` actions.

Note that you edit the receipts in a form for the report. This means, that you should hit the `ReportsController` and not the `ReceiptsController`.

If things do not work here is some debugging advice:

- execute rake routes to see if everything is defined correctly.
- Inspect the generated HTML from `form_for(@report)`. Especially the 'action=""' attribute of the form tag is relevant. It should point to "/reports/X"

EDIT: I created a Gist with all the relevant files to get a nested form working: https://gist.github.com/4420280

Comment: awesome thanks! 50 bounties for you! Quick question, how would I include a delete link in the form for each receipt? I tried adding nested resources for receipt with `resources :receipts, :only =>[:destroy, :edit, :show]` and the link_to `<%#= link_to 'Delete', receipt_path(@report, receipt.object.id), :method => :delete %>` but  Im getting a undefined method error `receipt_path`

Answer (score 0):

Do checkout cocoon gem for nested resources form. This gem has made a work lot easier dealing with nested resources. https://github.com/nathanvda/cocoon